# Prevent double entry for "Start Time" and "End Time" if already exists in the list

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

**Prevent double entry for "Start Time" and "End Time" if already exists in the list.**

*****For the same day.Also restrict from saving the item by providing a message to enter other time as this already exists. Preferably by using SPServices() and doing it on the PreSave() action. Thanks !

Comment: Can you please elaborate you question. With some good explanation which includes what you are trying to do and what you want to prevent.. This will give your question more attention.

Comment: Fetch the data in array or some variable using REST or any code. and check whether it is duplicate or not.

Comment: Asad my question is self explanatory !

Comment: You can go to the column settings of the list and enforce unique values for both the items. That way they won't be saved to the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use event receiver to achive this. Before event receiver  , in this you can write your business logic to check item is duplicate or not by Overriding the **itemAdding** event . Also can provide conditonal logic if duplicate do xyz.